# Numerical sum optimization

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, summation

I need to compute the following sum *as fast as possible*:
$$P_{ijkl}=\sum_{p,q,r,s}^nW_{sqpr}H_{js}G_{rl}A_{ipkq}$$

I came up with this code:

```
PP = Transpose[Flatten[H.W.G, {{1}, {4}, {2, 3}}].Flatten A, {{4, 2}, {3}, {1}}], {2, 4, 3, 1}];
```

which is approximately 50 times faster than the brute force implementation for dimensions `n=3`. I want to speed this computation as much as possible. Below I provide definitions of the ingredients. As can be seen, some matrices possess symmetries. You are free to use them, although I found it is hard. I am rather thinking in the direction of *correct index ordering* in the `Flatten` commands (there are several possibilities, but I do not know which one is better) and of compilation.

```
n = 3;
W = SymmetrizedArray[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n, n, n}], {n, n, n, n}, 
                      {{{4, 2, 3, 1}, 1}, {{1, 3, 2, 4}, 1}, {{2, 4, 1, 3}, 1}}];
g = RandomComplex[{0, 1 + I}, {n, n}];
G = g + ConjugateTranspose[g];
H = IdentityMatrix[n] - G;
a = SymmetrizedArray[RandomComplex[{0, 1 + I}, {n, n, n, n}], {n, n, n, n}, {{2, 1, 4, 3}, 1}];
A = a + Conjugate[Transpose[a, {3, 4, 1, 2}]];
```

It would be perfect if someone can beat the run-time of my code (likely) or even improve its scaling with respect to `n` (unlikely).

```
Timing[P = 
   Table[Sum[
     W[[s, q, p, r]] A[[i, p, k, q]] H[[j, s]] G[[r, l]], {p, n}, {q, 
      n}, {r, n}, {s, n}], {i, n}, {j, n}, {k, n}, {l, n}];]
Timing[PP = 
   Transpose[Flatten[H.W.G, {{1}, {4}, {2, 3}}].Flatten[A, {{4, 2}, {3}, {1}}], {2, 4, 3, 1}];]
Norm[Flatten[PP - P]];
(*{0.507595, Null}*)
(*{0.014532, Null}*)
(*2.06669*10^-14*)
```

Comment: `ArrayReshape` is slightly faster than `Flatten`, but the downside is that you have to give the dimensions explicitly rather than just asking for e.g. the second and third index to be flattened.

Comment: @ala10 Also `Compile` complains about complicated arguments in `Flatten`. Will it work with `ArrayReshape`?

Comment: My understanding is that compiling won't help too much here. `Dot` already calls some low-level C libraries and parallelizes everything automatically.

Comment: @ala10 Yes, I agree with you. However, I have a concern about the `Flatten` or `ArrayReshape` for that matter. I feel they are the bottleneck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to convert `W` and `A` to dense packed arrays with `Normal`; they are dense anyways and their symmetries do not compensate for not being able to use optimized dense matrix arithmetic. For `n=6`, this yields a 1000-fold speed-up:

```
n = 6;
W = SymmetrizedArray[
   RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n, n, n}], {n, n, n, 
    n}, {{{4, 2, 3, 1}, 1}, {{1, 3, 2, 4}, 1}, {{2, 4, 1, 3}, 1}}];
g = RandomComplex[{0, 1 + I}, {n, n}];
G = g + ConjugateTranspose[g];
H = IdentityMatrix[n] - G;
a = SymmetrizedArray[
   RandomComplex[{0, 1 + I}, {n, n, n, n}], {n, n, n, 
    n}, {{2, 1, 4, 3}, 1}];
A = a + Conjugate[Transpose[a, {3, 4, 1, 2}]];

nW = Normal[W];
nA = Normal[A];

PP = Transpose[
     Flatten[H.W.G, {{1}, {4}, {2, 3}}].Flatten[
       A, {{4, 2}, {3}, {1}}], {2, 4, 3, 1}]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
nPP = Transpose[
     Flatten[H.nW.G, {{1}, {4}, {2, 3}}].Flatten[
       nA, {{4, 2}, {3}, {1}}], {2, 4, 3, 1}]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
Max[Abs[PP - nPP]]
```

> 0.400711
>
> 0.000324
>
> 2.34371*10^-13

With a bit of more refactoring, I can get `PP` compute for `n=40` in half a second. The preparatory computations take significantly longer, though. (And I was under the impression that `SymmetrizedArray` might have some memory related bug that made my kernel quit at times.)

```
n = 40;
W = Normal@SymmetrizedArray[
    RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n, n, n}],
    {n, n, n, n},
    {{{4, 2, 3, 1}, 1}, {{1, 3, 2, 4}, 1}, {{2, 4, 1, 3}, 1}}
    ];
G = # + ConjugateTranspose[#] &[RandomComplex[{0, 1 + I}, {n, n}]];
H = IdentityMatrix[n, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision] - G;
A = # + Conjugate[Transpose[#, {3, 4, 1, 2}]] &[
   Normal@
    SymmetrizedArray[
     RandomComplex[{0, 1 + I}, {n, n, n, n}], {n, n, n, 
      n}, {{2, 1, 4, 3}, 1}]
   ];

PP = Transpose[
     Flatten[H.W.G, {{1}, {4}, {2, 3}}].Flatten[
       A, {{4, 2}, {3}, {1}}], {2, 4, 3, 1}]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.489619